# Using Azure AD without codebehind

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I am learning Windows Identity Foundation and trying to understand authentication via Azure AD using the web.config as described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mcsuksoldev/2012/10/18/access-to-an-asp-net-website-via-multiple-authentications/), but I can not understand, where to find **issuer** and **realm** for my application on [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com). Can anybody describe me where is it?

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? Understand Authentication Scenarios for Azure AD? The link you posted is not for Azure AD. It's different.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the *Issuer* in [Azure Portal - App Registrations](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ApplicationsListBlade) by selecting the 'Endpoint':

[image: Azure AD App Registrations - Endpoints]

You usually need only the first part of URL: the issuer refers to your tenant - which will usually be similar to https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Guid}

The *Realm* can be refereed as App Id URI in your App Registration: Select your application and click Settings/ Properties to find the value of this parameter.

However if your main objective is *to have an easy way to provide sign-in for Azure AD users without code change*, **Azure AD Express Authentication** may be an easier alternative: where we can just flip a switch to protect your web site so it only accepts sign-in from Azure AD accounts. For information about Express Auth, see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication).